# where can we find and watch ONAs?

Tags: resources

ONA is an anime that is directly released onto the Internet. And from my understanding, it should be like youtube site where you can watch it however you like, with video streaming or download it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Where can I found ONAs legally, and what should I do to watch it, should I register or pay something?

Comment: i know sometimes they are released on the offical sites or a bran new site is created for them like the Sword Art Online Extra Epiosde

Comment: Related: [Meta how can i tell if a site is legal](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal)

Comment: I guess you could research the origins of the most popular ONAs (or the ones you personally liked most) to find out where they first appeared. Maybe there's one place they all come from and we don't know it.

Comment: I found [this list of anime released on Youtube](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=8245) and [Niconico](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=11447) (ctrl+f "ONA")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of ONAs get released either through the [Bandai Channel](http://www.b-ch.com/) or on [Nico Nico Douga](http://www.nicovideo.jp/). Releases on the Bandai Channel are usually region locked and sometimes, they're re-release them on their [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/BandaiChannel) (which, sometimes, is also region locked). Nico has an English version of the site which makes it a lot more accessible.

Both sites are free, Nico requires registration to view most videos and there is also a "Premium" member access.